# Is it possible to configure Outlook in a way that it opens or previews any unknown file in a text editor (like VS Code or Notepad)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, text-editors, file-extension, attachments

At times, I get emails with files that have an unknown file extension (for example `.x-y-z`). Because this extension is unknown to Outlook (and virtually everyone on the planet), I can neither open the file nor preview it without first saving it and then opening it.

The content of these files is always text based, so I'd be happy if I could open or preview it in Notepad or VS Code directly from Outlook.

So, is there a way to configure Outlook in a way that it will open any unknown file in a text editoer?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I noticed that you want to preview the file with this unknown extension using notepad in Outlook. Because I don't have a file with the same unknown extension as you do, so I can't test it in my environment.

Based on my experience, it's suggested that you could set the default software to open these files to Notepad. For specific operations, please refer to:

1.Save this file locally;

2.Right click the file and select "open with";

3.Choose Notepad and select Always use this app to open .xxxxx files, click OK;
[image]

4.Then open the file with unknown extension in Outlook to check it there're any differences.

Hope to help you!

Comment: This is the solution for *one specific* unknown extension. But in my case, these extension change daily, and I hoped I could add a "generic" handler for all unknown extensions.

Comment: According to my research and testing, there seems to be no way to open files in multiple formats with one software in Outlook. 

As i know, when you first open a file with a new unknown extension, you will be prompted to choose which software to open and you could choose Notepad for every file with unknown extensions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirming my suspicion.

Comment: If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.